# Cannot find file from a webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am new to webpack and currently trying to go through some demos. However it seems that my server cannot find the file referenced from `index.html` file.

I am using `http-server`, and this is the `index.html` page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>

        <script src="../build/js/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve("src"),
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("build/js/"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".es6"]
    }
};
```

Currently I am trying to setup the following file structure:

**build**

- js

  - bundle.js

**src**

- js

  - App.js
- index.js

**public**

- index.html

After running `webpack` and starting the server I get a 404 error, stating that `bundle.js` could not be found.

Comment: That should work. What does the output from Webpack say?

Comment: the build process finishes successfully, I suspect I am messing something with these paths in the config file

Comment: please note that I am not using webpack-dev-server, instead I am using http-server if it has anything to do with it

Comment: Check your files. Does the bundle actually get output anywhere? The file path 
 webpack used should be shown in the webpack build info.